# Trying to divide a dataframe column by a float yields NaN

Tags: python, csv, pandas, division

**Background**
I deal with a csv datasheet that prints out columns of numbers.  I am working on a program that will take the first column, ask a user for a time in float (ie. 45 and a half hours = 45.5) and then subtract that number from the first column.  I have been successful in that regard.  Now, I need to find the row index of the "zero" time point.  I use min to find that index and then call that off of the following column A1.  I need to find the reading at Time 0 to then normalize A1 to so that on a graph, at the 0 time point the reading is 1 in column A1 (and eventually all subsequent columns but baby steps for me)

```
time_zero = float(input("Which time would you like to be set to 0?"))
df['A1']= df['A1']-time_zero
```

This works fine so far to set the zero time.

```
zero_location_series = df[df['A1'] == df['A1'].min()]
r1 = zero_location_series[' A1.1']
df[' A1.1'] = df[' A1.1']/r1
```

Here's where I run into trouble.  The first line will correctly identify a series that I can pull off of for all my other columns.  Next `r1` correctly identifies the proper A1.1 value and this value is a float when I use `type(r1)`.
However when I divide `df[' A1.1']/r1` it yields only one correct value and that value is where `r1/r1 = 1`.  All other values come out `NaN`.

My Questions:

1. How to divide a column by a float I guess?  Why am I getting `NaN`?
2. Is there a faster way to do this as I need to do this for 16 columns.(ie 'A2/r2' 'a3/r3' etc.)
3. Do I need to do inplace = True anywhere to make the operations stick prior to resaving the data? or is that only for adding/deleting rows?

**Example**

Dataframe that looks like this
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQxTM.png
zero time sets properly (image not shown)

after dividing the column
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA3te.png

Comment: Can you show a self-contained example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Often you get `NaN` when one of the operands is `NaN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to divide every value in the column by r1 it's best to apply, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5])
# apply an anonymous function to the first column ([0]), divide every value
# in the column by 3
df = df[0].apply(lambda x: x/3.0, 0)
print(df)
```

So you'd probably want something like this:

```
df = df["A1.1"].apply(lambda x: x/r1, 0)
```

This really only answers part 2 of you question. Apply is probably your best bet for running a function on multiple rows and columns quickly. As for why you're getting nans when dividing by a float, is it possible the values in your columns are anything other than floats or integers?

Comment: This works!  I have a new problem now but I think i can probably troubleshoot that on my own (using min() when I want the smallest > 0 min).  Sorry it took me so long to respond (overestimated my time over the holiday to work on this) and thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df['A1.1']=df['A1.1']/df['A1.1'].min()
```

I think the reason `df[' A1.1'] = df[' A1.1']/r1` did not work was because `r1` is a series. Try `r1?` instead of `type(r1)` and pandas will tell you that `r1` is a series, not an individual float number.

To do it in one attempt, you have to iterate over each column, like this:

```
for c in df:
    df[c] = df[c]/df[c].min()
```